# Why does tflite cmake build documentation show building tflite as separate library

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, tflite

In the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake) for building tflite with cmake, steps 1-5 mention building the libtensorflow-lite.a static library file in tflite_build directory (if you don't explicitly specify `-DTFLITE_ENABLE_INSTALL=ON` to build an installable package). However, note in [step 5](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#step_5_build_tensorflow_lite) mentions that the library is not self contained and you have to use it like in the [minimal example](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#create_a_cmake_project_which_uses_tensorflow_lite) at the end of the guide. The example CMakeLists.txt specifies following:

```
add_subdirectory(
  "${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

This causes the tensorflow-lite library to get built during the build step of the minimal example.

What is then the use of the steps 1-5 in the guide if the `libtensorflow-lite.a` generated in tflite_build isn't self-contained and the whole thing has to be built by CMakeLists.txt of the project requiring to use the library?

I tried removing the following lines in CMakeLists.txt of the minimal example:

```
add_subdirectory(
  "${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

and adding the full path to the prebuilt tensorflow-lite library in

```
target_link_libraries(minimal tensorflow-lite)
```

but the compiler complained about not being able to find `tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"`